# Java POJO with MongoDB not extracting data

Tags: java, mongodb

I am working on java first time. database is MongoDB. and I am trying to extract data from MongoDB. following the [link](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.5/driver/getting-started/quick-start-pojo/)

Below is code for database query

```
MongoCollection<Person> collection = database.getCollection("people", Person.class);

BasicDBObject whereQuery = new BasicDBObject();

List<BasicDBObject> obj = new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>();

obj.add(new BasicDBObject("name","someName"));
obj.add(new BasicDBObject("age","someAge"));
whereQuery.put("$and", obj);

FindIterable<Person> iterDoc = collection.find(whereQuery);
MongoCursor<Person> it = iterDoc.iterator();

while (it.hasNext()) {  

  Person data = it.next();
  System.out.println(data);

}
```

**I am using same POJO from link**

when I run code, I get below output

**com.test.pojo.document.Person@6572421**

What does this output means and why it is not showing result. If I skip POJO and use it like below then it works fine shows result from database

```
MongoClient mongo = MongoClients.create("mongodb://localhost:27017");

MongoDatabase database = mongo.getDatabase("DBname");  

MongoCollection<Person> collection = database.getCollection("people");

BasicDBObject whereQuery = new BasicDBObject();

List<BasicDBObject> obj = new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>();

obj.add(new BasicDBObject("name","someName"));
obj.add(new BasicDBObject("age","someAge"));
whereQuery.put("$and", obj);

FindIterable<Person> iterDoc = collection.find(whereQuery);
MongoCursor<Person> it = iterDoc.iterator();

while (it.hasNext()) {  

  Person data = it.next();
  System.out.println(data);

}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4

Comment: Got it. Thank you